# Passport check for non-EU(Wizzair)

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel, passport-stamps

I'm an Israeli flying from Gdansk to Turku with Wizzair, checking in online with carry-on bag only. My plan was to go straight through security to the gate. However, I noticed on their website that non-EU citizens are required to have their passport and visa checked, and their boarding pass stamped, or else it would be invalid and boarding could be denied. I haven't actually printed my boarding pass yet because online check-in is still closed.

So here are my questions:

- What happens if I use a mobile boarding pass? How do you stamp those? Is Mobile boarding pass even available in Gdansk airport?
- How strictly is it enforced?
- My flight is early in the morning, so I would appreciate saving time and not have to be present in the airport earlier than necessary. Waiting in line for the check in desk can be troublesome. However, I land in the same airport a few days earlier so I figured, would it be possible to have it checked and stamped in advance? Alternatively, can in be done in the city terminal a day before the flight? What can you tell me about the terminal in Gdansk city centre? What services to they provide. I know Wizz has representatives there but do they offer check in services? Or better yet, Wizz also have desks in Tel Aviv Ben Gurion airport. I actually fly to Gdansk with Lot and not Wizz, but perhaps I could take care of it as soon as possible?

On a different subject:

- Middle name: 
  My brother has one(we're flying together), it's on the passport but I didn't know when booking so it's not on the ticket. 
  i.e John Smith on the ticket, John Patrick Smith on the passport. I know it's been asked many times, just from a quick search I found dozens of answers. Everybody said they had never had a problem. But when I wrote Wizz and Lot, they both said I should change the name, and of course they want a fee that is higher than the price I paid for the tickets. I'm not willing to pay that as a matter of principle but I don't want any trouble. Did they give me that answer just so I pay the fee or is it really a big deal?

Thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: You simply have to show up on check-in receive "documents checked" sticker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I found it strange as those requirements usually are from RyanAir, and WizzAir is much more flexible, but anyway):

> What happens if I use a mobile boarding pass? How do you stamp those?
>   Is Mobile boarding pass even available in Gdansk airport?

In this case you will NOT get a mobile boarding pass. You will be allowed to complete online checkin, but then asked to print the boarding pass (sent to your email or downloaded from website). RyanAir is doing this for those flights.

> How strictly is it enforced?

It is not enforced. I have flown tons of those flights last two years, and never did the dedicated document check on either airline. What happens then is one of three things:

- A special announcement for everyone with non-EU passport to line up to the counter, and does the document check.
- When you attempt to board without check, you're pulled aside and they do the document check (basically retyping into computer everything you have typed already during online checkin) while boarding continues;
- When you attempt to board without check, they hold the line, type your data in, and let you through.

It is also my opinion (which some people disagree with) that if you are denied boarding in this case, you shall be eligible for compensation according to EU 261. But I never had a chance to test this yet.

> However, I land in the same airport a few days earlier so I figured,
>   would it be possible to have it checked and stamped in advance?

I tried this two years ago, and they refused to stamp it even one day in advance - they said this could only be done once your flight opens for airport check in. And this could be done only at a place where they offer check in (i.e. not ticket sales counter).

> Did they give me that answer just so I pay the fee or is it really a
>   big deal?

They gave you that answer so you just paid the fee (or didn't understand the issue). As far as I remember, WizzAir only asks for First/Last name and gender. There is no space to enter your middle name at all.